# error while mapping database schema

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

When I try to map with subsonic 3.0.0.3 database, i get error:

"Running transformation: System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one matching element..."

Where i should look for error?

Comment: Please post the code that generates this error

Answer (score 0):

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL';

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `osm2` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET cp1251 COLLATE cp1251_general_ci;
USE `osm2`;

---

-- Table `mydb`.`sw_profile`

---

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `osm2`.`sw_profile` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `configuration` VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL ,
  `comments` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;

---

-- Table `mydb`.`sw_type`

---

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `osm2`.`sw_type`(
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR (45) NOT NULL,
  `ports_num` INT NOT NULL,
  `trunc_ports` VARCHAR (45) NOT NULL,
  `supports_dhcp` TINYINT (1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
ENGINE = INNODB;

---

-- Table `mydb`.`sw`

---

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `osm2`.`sw`(
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `sn` VARCHAR (45) NULL,
  `mac` VARCHAR (45) NOT NULL,
  `ip` VARCHAR (45) NOT NULL,
  `comments` VARCHAR (45) NULL,
  `sw_profile_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `sw_type_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_sw_sw_profile` (`sw_profile_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_sw_sw_type1` (`sw_type_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_sw_sw_profile`
  FOREIGN KEY (`sw_profile_id`)
  REFERENCES `mydb`.`sw_profile` (`id`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_sw_sw_type1`
  FOREIGN KEY (`sw_type_id`)
  REFERENCES `mydb`.`sw_type` (`id`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
ENGINE = INNODB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = cp1251;

---

-- Table `mydb`.`port`

---

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `osm2`.`port`(
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR (45) NOT NULL,
  `state` TINYINT (1) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` INT NULL,
  `sw_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_port_sw1` (`sw_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_port_sw1`
  FOREIGN KEY (`sw_id`)
  REFERENCES `mydb`.`sw` (`id`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
ENGINE = INNODB;

---

-- Table `mydb`.`vlan`

---

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `osm2`.`vlan`(
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR (45) NOT NULL,
  `tag` VARCHAR (45) NOT NULL,
  `comments` VARCHAR (500) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
ENGINE = INNODB;

---

-- Table `mydb`.`address`

---

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `osm2`.`address`(
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR (45) NOT NULL,
  `short_name` VARCHAR (45) NOT NULL,
  `comments` VARCHAR (45) NULL,
  `sw_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_address_sw1` (`sw_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_address_sw1`
  FOREIGN KEY (`sw_id`)
  REFERENCES `mydb`.`sw` (`id`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
ENGINE = INNODB;

---

-- Table `mydb`.`tariff`

---

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `osm2`.`tariff`(
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR (45) NOT NULL,
  `price` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  `speed` VARCHAR (45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
ENGINE = INNODB;

---

-- Table `mydb`.`client`

---

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `osm2`.`client`(
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `utm_id` VARCHAR (45) NULL,
  `utm_login` VARCHAR (45) NULL,
  `ip` VARCHAR (45) NOT NULL,
  `ip_second` VARCHAR (45) NULL,
  `contacts` VARCHAR (500) NULL,
  `comments` VARCHAR (500) NULL,
  `act` VARCHAR (500) NULL,
  `vlan_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `address_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `tariff_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_client_vlan1` (`vlan_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_client_address1` (`address_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_client_tariff1` (`tariff_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_client_vlan1`
  FOREIGN KEY (`vlan_id`)
  REFERENCES `mydb`.`vlan` (`id`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_client_address1`
  FOREIGN KEY (`address_id`)
  REFERENCES `mydb`.`address` (`id`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_client_tariff1`
  FOREIGN KEY (`tariff_id`)
  REFERENCES `mydb`.`tariff` (`id`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
ENGINE = INNODB;

---

-- Table `mydb`.`port_has_vlan`

---

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `osm2`.`port_has_vlan`(
  `port_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `vlan_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`port_id`, `vlan_id`),
  INDEX `fk_port_has_vlan_port1` (`port_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_port_has_vlan_vlan1` (`vlan_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_port_has_vlan_port1`
  FOREIGN KEY (`port_id`)
  REFERENCES `mydb`.`port` (`id`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_port_has_vlan_vlan1`
  FOREIGN KEY (`vlan_id`)
  REFERENCES `mydb`.`vlan` (`id`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
ENGINE = INNODB;

---

-- Table `mydb`.`request_state`

---

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `osm2`.`request_state`(
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR (45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
ENGINE = INNODB;

---

-- Table `mydb`.`request_type`

---

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `osm2`.`request_type`(
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR (45) NOT NULL,
  `comments` VARCHAR (500) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
ENGINE = INNODB;

---

-- Table `mydb`.`request`

---

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `osm2`.`request`(
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `comments` VARCHAR (500) NULL,
  `log` VARCHAR (500) NULL,
  `request_state_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `request_type_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `client_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_request_request_state1` (`request_state_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_request_request_type1` (`request_type_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_request_client1` (`client_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_request_request_state1`
  FOREIGN KEY (`request_state_id`)
  REFERENCES `mydb`.`request_state` (`id`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_request_request_type1`
  FOREIGN KEY (`request_type_id`)
  REFERENCES `mydb`.`request_type` (`id`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_request_client1`
  FOREIGN KEY (`client_id`)
  REFERENCES `mydb`.`client` (`id`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
ENGINE = INNODB;

---

-- Table `mydb`.`department`

---

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `osm2`.`department`(
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR (45) NOT NULL,
  `comments` VARCHAR (45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
ENGINE = INNODB;

---

-- Table `mydb`.`group`

---

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `osm2`.`group`(
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR (45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
ENGINE = INNODB;

---

-- Table `mydb`.`account`

---

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `osm2`.`account`(
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `login` VARCHAR (45) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR (45) NOT NULL,
  `group_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_account_group1` (`group_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_account_group1`
  FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`)
  REFERENCES `mydb`.`group` (`id`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
ENGINE = INNODB;

---

-- Table `mydb`.`staff`

---

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `osm2`.`staff`(
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR (45) NOT NULL,
  `contacts` VARCHAR (45) NOT NULL,
  `department_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `account_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_staff_department1` (`department_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_staff_account1` (`account_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_staff_department1`
  FOREIGN KEY (`department_id`)
  REFERENCES `mydb`.`department` (`id`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_staff_account1`
  FOREIGN KEY (`account_id`)
  REFERENCES `mydb`.`account` (`id`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
ENGINE = INNODB;

---

-- Table `mydb`.`fid`

---

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `osm2`.`fid`(
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `text` VARCHAR (500) NOT NULL,
  `comments` VARCHAR (500) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
ENGINE = INNODB;

---

-- Table `mydb`.`group_has_fid`

---

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `osm2`.`group_has_fid`(
  `group_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `fid_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`group_id`, `fid_id`),
  INDEX `fk_group_has_fid_group1` (`group_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_group_has_fid_fid1` (`fid_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_group_has_fid_group1`
  FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`)
  REFERENCES `mydb`.`group` (`id`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_group_has_fid_fid1`
  FOREIGN KEY (`fid_id`)
  REFERENCES `mydb`.`fid` (`id`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
ENGINE = INNODB;

SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I found problem.

There are some tables with 2 fields with property primary key (through this tables uses connection many to many) in my schema.

Is it bug?